# Can't edit rows in phpmyadmin if the database has geometry columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I added a column of geometry type to my database and now I can't edit any row from phpMyAdmin. First, if I try to delete a row it shows me the detailed SQL and the geometry column data is replaced by some weird chars, I suppose this is why it can't delete it because the column is used in the WHERE.

If I try to edit it the normal form is not presented, but a new SELECT SQL is presented, however from here I don't have much success in editing it either.

Is the phpMyAdmin broken or how can I edit my rows?

Comment: Have you tried editiing the table by terminal or another client f.e. http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/manager/download to check if pgadmin is the reason or your db installation?

Comment: I gave up, i tried Adminer without success. I can delete if i write the sql and ignore the geometry column but if i try to edit a row i get an empty form. I removed the geometry column so i can work on my database, i'll re add it in the future if necessary.